# Can we add multiple images for a single product in prestashop

Tags: prestashop

Is it possible to add multiple images per product in prestashop? Is there any module for that? Any one please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, sure. You can import products (in bulk) with multiple images or add them one by one using Store Manager for PrestaShop. Get more details about this extension [here](http://www.prestashopmanager.com/)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

In your backoffice, edit your product and go to the "Pictures" tab, the form allow you to upload a zip containing multiple images.